# Formas de actualizar elementos tipo vista

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Esta es una duda que siempre he tenido, siempre he salido del paso de formas un poco *chapuceras* y es por eso que me he animado a preguntar esto.

> **¿Que distintas formas existen para actualizar elementos de tipo vista?**

Pongamos que tenemos un formulario, básico, `Form1`, con su `Form1.cs` y a parte de este tenemos una clase llamada `Vista` o `Clase`.
Como en este *diagrama* de aquí abajo.

[image: Diagrama]

La idea es recopilar **distintas formas y ejemplos** de actualizar estos elementos de tipo vista, en este caso una `Label` cuadno pulsemos un `Button`, de forma de que se puedan aplicar a otro tipo de elementos.

La clase `Form1`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }
}
```

Clase de ejemplo:

```
class Class1 {



    // Metodo para actualizar la label 
    // Ejemplo: 

     Label devolverLabel() {
        var label = new Label();
        label.Text = "Hola mundo";

        return label;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Algo que suelo utilizar es lo siguiente.

1- Creo una `clase` con `propiedades` replicadas a las que necesitaré actualizar en este caso solo es una `label`.

```
class ReplicaVista {

    public Label label { get; set; }

    public ReplicaVista() {
        this.label = new Label();
        this.label.Text = ""; //Inicializo la label para evitar valores null
    }


}
```

2- Creo un objeto en la clase desde la que actualizaré los elementos.

```
//Creamos objeto
static ReplicaVista formulario = new ReplicaVista();

void ActualizarLabel() {

    //Lo actualizamos
    formulario.label.Text = "Hola mundo!";
}
```

3- Usando un `timer` voy actualizando las propiedades en el `Form1`.

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        label1.Text = Class1.formulario.label.Text;

    }
```

> Esto generalmente lo suelo utilizar cuando trabajo con `Threads`, `Tasks`... para tener una especie de Nodo donde recopilo las clases, sin tener que llenar la clase del `Form1` de llamadas a métodos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar el patrón Redux que se usa en páginas web hechas con React, con eso manejas el estado de tu aplicación de forma global, y es thread-safe ya que el estado es inmutable.

Ejemplos de implementaciones del patrón Redux en C# tienes varios:

Tienes Redux.Net: https://github.com/GuillaumeSalles/redux.NET

O Reducto:
https://github.com/pshomov/reducto

Aquí un ejemplo con Reducto (que es el que yo he utilizado):

Primero defines una estructura donde estarán los datos que quieres tener a nivel global:

```
public struct AppState
{
    public string ValorLabel; // este sería el texto que quieres poner en los labels en todos los formularios
}
```

Luego creas una "accion" para cada dato que has declarado, solo puedes modificar el estado por medio de acciones, no de forma directa:

```
// esta acción cambia el valor de la label a otro texto
public struct CambiaLabel { 
    public string NuevoValor { get; set;}
}

// esta acción borra el texto de la label
public struct BorraLabel {
    // no le agregamos ninguna propiedad porque simplemente borra el texto
}
```

Luego creas los reducers, los reducers son los que modifican o alteran el estado:

```
var reducer = new SimpleReducer<AppState>()
    .When<CambiaLabel>((state, action) => {
        // la store nos pasa el estado actual (en state) y la acción que se va a realizar (en action)
        state.ValorLabel = action.NuevoValor; // modificamos el estado con el valor que viene en la action
        return state; // regresamos el nuevo estado
    })
    .When<BorraLabel>((state, action) => {
        // de nuevo la store nos pasa el estado actual (en state) y la acción a realizar, pero en este caso la acción no trae ningún parámetro
        state.ValorLabel = string.Empty; // modificamos el estado
        return state; // regresamos el estado
    });
```

Y por último creas el objeto store, que es el que contiene el estado de tu aplicación:

```
var store = new Store<AppState>(reducer); // le pasamos el reducer que creamos anteriormente
```

Puedes hacerlo un singleton sin problema, solo declaralo de solo lectura:

```
public static class Store
{
     readonly Store<AppState> store;
     static Store()
     {
           var reducer = new SimpleReducer<AppState>()
              .When<CambiaLabel>((state, action) => {
                  state.ValorLabel = action.NuevoValor;
                  return state;
               });
           store = new Store<AppState>(reducer);
     }

     public static Store<AppState> Instance => store;
 }
```

Y listo, para actualizar el estado solo tienes que escribir:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     Store.Instance.Dispatch(new CambiaLabel { NuevoValor = "Hola mundo" }); 
}
```

Lo puedes hacer desde cualquier parte del código.

Y para saber cuando cambia el estado (y así actualizas en todas las vistas):

```
// Subscribe se va a ejecutar cada vez que en alguna parte se modifica el estado por medio de una acción
Store.Instance.Subscribe(state =  {
        // en state nos llega el estado ya actualizado
        // y puedes usarlo para lo que quieras
        label.Text = state.ValorLabel;
    });
```

Por ejemplo, si tienes varios formularios y quieras tener un label que diga lo mismo en todos, pues usas el código anterir en cada uno, y su contenido se va a sincronizar.

La idea es que no caigas en malos habitos cayendo en la tentación de usar un Singleton mutable, queno es nada recomendable, un singleton inmutable es mejor.

Comment: Es una forma interesante que desconocía, hay varios conceptos que no llego a entender como `singleton mutable / inmutable` o `reducer` . Podrías explicar un poco mejor? Generalmente trabajo con aplicaciones de consola y hay algunas cositas que se me escapan.

Comment: Singleton es un patrón que garntiza que habrá un sola instancia de un objeto, y que está disponible de forma global, en este caso, en c# se implementa con clases estáticas. Un objeto mutable permite realizar cambios en su estado, por ejemplo, una clase con propiedades que tienen get y set es mutable, por el contrario, un objeto inmutable es aquel que después de haber sido creado no puede ser modicado, incluso por la misma clase. Reducer en el caso del patrón Redux, es el nombre que se le da a al código que modifca el estado que gurdas en la store.